# Redux dispatch type for function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

What would be the dispatch type of redux function? which does not contain type property?

For example, here I am doing `any` which works but what would be actual type here?

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch:any) => ({
  updateProject: (project: ProjectBody) => dispatch(updateProject(project))
})
```

my update project looks like this

```
export function update(project: ProjectBody) {
  return async (dispatch: Dispatch<UpdateStateAction>) => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(`${project.id}`, {
      // sme code
    dispatch({
      type: SUCCESS_UPDATE_PROJECT,
      payload: { project: json.project }
    })
```

Comment: were you satisfied with the answer I provided below or do you have further questions?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is use an object instead of a function and `dispatch` is bound for you:

```js
const mapDispatch = {
  updateProject
}
```

The medium answer is `Dispatch` is a generic type, so you can pass the shape of object/s that your action creator generates as the argument. If you have multiple action creators you are mapping to `props` use the syntax: `Dispatch<IActionCreatorIncCount | IActionCreatorDecCount>`

```js
import {Dispatch} from 'react-redux'

const INC_COUNT = 'INC_COUNT'

interface IActionCreatorIncCount {
  payload: number
  type: typeof INC_COUNT
}

const actionCreatorIncCount = (n: number): IActionCreatorIncCount =>
  ({ payload: n, type: INC_COUNT })

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<IActionCreatorIncCount>) => ({
incCount: actionCreatorIncCount
})
```

The long answer is don't use `mapDispatchToProps` anymore and instead use the hooks alternatives `useSelector` and `useDispatch`. You can find more information [here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript).